# Do domain registrar affect the ping time of your domain? How to optimize?

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, nameserver

The background story: recently I switched to use cloudflare as the name-server of my domain(which use namecheap as registrar). I noticed a increase in ping time. 
Then, I moved another domain(with godaddy as registrar) to Cloudflare and I actually see improvement.

The difference between the two is non trivial (200ms vs 3ms). The machine behind the two domain is in the same datacenter. It makes me wonder is it because the difference in registrar.

Do domain registrar affect the ping time of your domain? If so or otherwise, How can I optimize?

Comment: Why do you care about ping? Certainly your app doesn't run on ICMP.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but is ping time correlates with first load time?

Comment: ICMP performance doesn't necessarily correlate to TCP or UDP performance. Ping is a bad statistic to measure for this.

Comment: Yes, it is especially true when using CloudFlare. Since we use an Anycast network, pinging the CloudFlare IPs is not going to return solid results. Users should use a traceroute instead of a ping.

Answer (score 3):

No, the registrar has no influence at the ping time.

The DNS Server has. All what the registrar does is set up the registration information at the corresponding top level domain server's. I.e. if you get a .com domain, they are informed about where your name servers are.

So, the only way a registrar can make that slow is if he runs (crappy) dns servers.

Cloudflare generally should be very fast - I would contact their support. They run a top notch very distributed architecture.

Answer (score 2):

The time for the first ping might be affected by slow DNS servers of a given registrar, but subsequent pings should be unaffected.